# Connecting to database using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed Oracle SQL Developer and exemplary database - [Nothwind](http://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/releases/view/71634).

How to connect to this database? What is username, password, hostname? Is it possible?
I found only instructions for other programs and there is written: "write these parameters", without giving them.

Comment: You've tagged this Oracle.  But the sample database you linked to is a SQL Server database.  Are you trying to connect to an Oracle database?  Or to a SQL Server database?  If you are trying to connect to SQL Server, have you installed the SQL Server JDBC driver in Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: I am trying to connect to SQL server and SQL Server JDBC driver in Oracle SQL Developer is not installed.

Comment: What??? One more time please and with details.

Comment: It is my first configuration of database. Earlier I had database connection configured and I wrote only SQL queries. I downloaded exemplary database from Internet in format .bak. It is on my local disk and I try to connect to it. Is it possible? If no, what type of exemplary database should I find? I want only to execute queries.

Comment: Search for the appropiate driver, get it and import it. Perhaps this might give you a lead... http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/thirdparty-095608.html

Comment: The *.bak is a backup of a database.  Just download NorthWind from CodePlex and install via the MSI Installer.  Code to create a admin user is below.

Comment: I installed drivers from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/thirdparty-095608.html and I found database in format *.mdb. Is it enough? During connection the error message appears: "Status : Failure -Test failed: [Microsoft][Driver Manager ODBC]Could not find name of data source, default driver is not given". CRAFTY_DBA, I need login and password? Without it I cannot connect?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at codeplex to see if any sample logins and/or users are created.

http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/72278

If not, I will post a snippet to create a login/user with data_reader / data_writer privileges.

Run this script on the SQL Server database using SSMS.  You then can use the [ADW_ADMIN] account that has db_owner privileges for testing.  The password is listed below.

```
-- Which database to use.
USE [master]
GO


-- Delete existing login.
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'ADW_ADMIN')
DROP LOGIN [ADW_ADMIN]
GO

-- Add new login.
CREATE LOGIN [ADW_ADMIN] WITH PASSWORD=N'M0a2r0c9h11$', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[AdventureWorks2012]
GO

-- Which database to use.
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO

-- Delete existing user.
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'ADW_ADMIN')
DROP USER [ADW_ADMIN]
GO

-- Add new user.
CREATE USER [ADW_ADMIN] FOR LOGIN [ADW_ADMIN] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO



-- Which database to use.
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO

-- Add to database owner role 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'ADW_ADMIN'
GO

-- Add to database read / write roles
--EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'ADW_USER'
--EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'ADW_USER'
GO
```